# Homepage has Paged Pages that should not exist, like /page/2/ and on to /page/99999/

Tags: pagination, homepage

The backstory is I noticed the homepage was generating infinite paginated pages. This is a custom built theme.

I was using index.php and WP_Query to create 2 small 5 post loops. I figured WP_Query was pulling all of the qualifying posts and then limiting to the most recent 5, so I switched to get_posts with a foreach loop, since my understanding is that doesn't fetch all the posts, only the ones you ask for (and therefore no need for pagination). This didn't solve the issue.

Then I realized that the Settings > Readings were set to show Latest Posts, which explained why Yoast was auto-adding a "next" schema with a link to page/2/ though it shouldn't exist. By changing that to a static page and moving index.php to front-page.php, that killed off the "next" schema.

However, you can still manually go to /page/2/ on to /page/24893/ and so forth, and it still loads the same posts as page one instead of giving off a 404 error.

The problem here is that with the "next" schema having been there, Google could be indexing all that bloat infinitely. It's not, but it's a potential. The real problem is it's driving me nuts and I don't want this to be the case that those pages exist. Since they were previously exposed I'd like them to 404 now.

Every Wordpress site I've checked that I can think of that has a static homepage has the problem.

Does anybody know what's triggering this? I'm doing small static loops with get_posts and have no pagination setup and it's set to a static front-page.php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To remove relational links from the single post `<head>` use

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head' );
```

`adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head` [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head/).

To return Status 404 on paginated pages use `.htaccess` rule similar to following:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([0-9]+)/$ http://yourdomain.tld/404/ [R=404,NC,L]
```

`.htaccess` rule is not tested, but it gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

The logic handling the URL paths is located at wp-includes/canonical.php:414 Basically the code decides to serve front page at the requested URL no matter if you actually use paged content. A non future proof (the code might get changed in future updates) fix would be:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function () {
    if (is_front_page()) {
        set_query_var('page', 1);
    }
});
```

This lets WordPress to handle the redirect further.

A more future proof version:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function () {
    if (is_front_page() && get_query_var('page')) {
        wp_redirect('/', 301);

        exit();
    }
});
```